# Issue extending django User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a website where the user should be able to sign up as a "worker" or a "customer", an uber model type of site. I created the two models `WorkerProfile` and `CustomerProfile` and the two forms, but each time I submit either the customer or worker form, the new user gets put in both the Customer profile's and Worker profile's in the database at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ , how do I prevent this from happening?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class WorkerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'USER')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_worker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        WorkerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_worker_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.workerprofile.save()







class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'CUSTOMER')
    needLaundryDone = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CustomerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_customer_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customerprofile.save()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class WorkerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #birth_date and university fields need to be declared seperately because they are not apart of User:
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    university = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'birth_date',
                  'university',
                  'password1',
                  'password2', )


class CustomerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #birth_date and university fields need to be declared seperately because they are not apart of User:
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    university = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'birth_date',
                  'university',
                  'password1',
                  'password2', )
```

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_worker = WorkerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        form_customer = CustomerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form_worker.is_valid():
            user = form_worker.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.workerprofile.birth_date = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.workerprofile.university = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('university')
            user.save()  # explicitly save custom fields not in User model
            raw_password = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)  # login user after signup
            return redirect('home')
        elif form_customer.is_valid():
            user = form_customer.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.customerprofile.birth_date = form_customer.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.customerprofile.university = form_customer.cleaned_data.get('university')
            user.save()  # explicitly save custom fields not in User model
            raw_password = form_customer.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)  # login user after signup
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form_worker = WorkerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        form_customer = CustomerSignUpForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'core/signup.html', {'form_worker': form_worker,'form_customer': form_customer })
```

signup.html:

```
{%  extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    <title> Sign Up</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}


  <h3>Sign Up As Worker</h3>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_worker.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>

   <h3>Sign Up As Customer</h3>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_customer.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use signals here. They both fire on save of User, and each create their related object.

You should remove those signals and instead do this in the view. In the `is_valid` block for each form you can create only the specific object you need.

```
if form_worker.is_valid():
    user = form_worker.save()
    worker = WorkerProfile(user=user)
    worker.birth_date = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
    worker.university = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('university')
    worker.save()
    raw_password = form_worker.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    ...
elif form_customer.is_valid():
    user = form_customer.save()
    customer = CustomerProfile(user=user)
    ...
```

Comment: I agree with Daniel, don't use signals.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the view as you said, it was too long for comments so I put it here https://jsfiddle.net/jkm74fv4/ . But now everything is being stored as a "worker" profile, even if I sign up as a customer?

Comment: You need to use prefixes when you instantiate the forms to distinguish between them. Although looking more closely, I can't really understand why you have two forms at all; why not one form, with a checkbox for worker/customer?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal :

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you call this in both models, so during the save(), it will create both.

What I propose you, is to modify your models. Why don't you just create a model 'Profil' and put a boolean field 'is_customer' True/False ?

Comment: I plan on adding features such as if you are a customer you press a button and it signals you are looking for someone to provide a service (boolean field for customer such as 'lookingForService') and then would have to add things such as payment information (where to send payment for worker and where to get payment from customer) . Would it be okay if customers/workers each had certain fields in 'Profile' that were always equal to null or an empty string (i.e a worker would not need the 'lookingForService' field), so would it okay to just leave this false for workers?

Comment: This is not a problem if you leave some field as Null or False. I mean, basically this is not rare in an application that a user doesn't fill all his profile's fields.